# How to add filter on a dynamically generated object strings values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to coding, and I have a dynamically generated Object data as this:

```
data: {
    1-leadTimeNormal: 10
    3-leadTimeNormal: 22
    2-leadTimeNormal: 10
    2-leadTimeOptimal: 2
    3-leadTimeOptimal: 22
    1-leadTimeOptimal: 7
}
```

Where, the integer value on the left hand side(1,3,2, etc) is getting generated dynamically.
Now, I want to put a condition to check whether 1-leadTimeNormal is less than 1-leadTimeOptimal or not (using if Else) and 2-leadTimeNormal is less than 2-leadTimeOptimal or not and so on and return some string in console log using javascript

Comment: new to coding or new to javascript? if its javascript we can help else......

Comment: I am new to both

Comment: That's invalid json or js object

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each value from 1 to number of keys/2

```js
data = {
 '1-leadTimeNormal': 10,
 '3-leadTimeNormal': 22,
 '2-leadTimeNormal': 10,
 '2-leadTimeOptimal': 2,
 '3-leadTimeOptimal': 22,
 '1-leadTimeOptimal': 7
}
let arr = Object.keys(data)

for(let i=1; i<=arr.length/2; i++) {
 if(data[`${i}-leadTimeNormal`] < data[`${i}-leadTimeOptimal`]) {
  console.log('hello world')
 } else {
  console.log('bye world')
 }
}
```

If you dont know the appended numbers, you can filter them out

```js
data = {
 '1-leadTimeNormal': 10,
 '3-leadTimeNormal': 22,
 '2-leadTimeNormal': 10,
 '2-leadTimeOptimal': 2,
 '3-leadTimeOptimal': 22,
 '1-leadTimeOptimal': 7
}
let keys = Object.keys(data).filter(key => key.includes('leadTimeNormal'))

keys.forEach(key => {
 let num = key.replace(/^([0-9]+)-.*/, '$1')
 if (data[key] < data[`${num}-leadTimeOptimal`]) {
  console.log('hello world')
 } else {
  console.log('bye world')
 }
});
```

Comment: what append if the object contains non consecutive keys ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) string as key to access your `data` value

```
const n = 1 // may be a number or string
if (data[`${n}-leadTimeNormal`] > data[`${n}-leadTimeOptimal`]) {
    // ....
}
```

Comment: I don't know I will be getting "1" all the time  in that string or something else. That is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
    "1-leadTimeNormal": 10,
    "3-leadTimeNormal": 22,
    "4-leadTimeNormal": 22,
    "4-leadTimeOptimal": 42,
    "3-leadTimeOptimal": 22,
    "1-leadTimeOptimal": 7,
    "otherRandomKey": "Hello, World!"
}

// iterate over keys
for (let key in data) {
  // ensure key is in the form "x-leadTimeNormal"
  if (key.match(/\d+-.+Normal/)) {
    // get the number part
    let number = key.substring(0, key.indexOf("-"))
    // test inferiority
    if (data[number + "-leadTimeNormal"] < data[number + "-leadTimeOptimal"]) {
      console.log("log here for number " + number)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `/\d+-.+Normal/`

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = {
 '1-leadTimeNormal': 10,
 '3-leadTimeNormal': 22,
 '2-leadTimeNormal': 10,
 '2-leadTimeOptimal': 2,
 '3-leadTimeOptimal': 22,
 '1-leadTimeOptimal': 7
}
const arr = Object.keys(data);
const leadTimeNormals = arr.filter(i => i.includes("leadTimeNormal"));

leadTimeNormals.forEach(item => {
  const [number,] = item.split("-");
  if(arr[item] < arr[`${number}-leadTimeOptimal`]) {
    console.log("It is here");
  } else {
    console.log("it is not here");
  }
});
```

Hope this helps